# How to push SQL Query from Console Output into an Excel File?

Tags: excel, perl

I'm new at coding and so here.

Right now I'm creating an perl script, which automatically creates an excel file with the output of an SQL Query.

**SQL Query:**

```
init_db_connections();
my @row;
my $curHnd = INV::DBI::execute('----'.':------') or die $INV::DBI::errstr;
while ($row[0] = $curHnd->fetchrow_hashref()) {
        printf("Row1: >%s<\n", $row[0]{Row1}),
        printf("Row2: >%s<\n", $row[0]{Row2}),
        printf("Row3:      >%s<\n", $row[0]{Row3})
}
exit 0;

sub init_db_connections {
    INV::DBI::init({
        ------         => '--------',
        ------- => q{select Row1, Row2, Row3
from table1
}
```

**Create the Excel:**

```
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'perl.xlsx' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my $format = $workbook->add_format();
$format->set_bold();
$format->set_color( 'black' );
$format->set_underline;
 
my $col = my $row = 0;
$worksheet->write( $row, $col, 'SQL Report', $format );

$workbook->close();
```

---

My Problem is now that i don't know how i can combine these two, so that the Query gets automatically pushed into the Excel.

Any Ideas would be great.

Comment: Your Excel file seems to be empty. And you do not seem to print your SQL query to file.

Comment: Is there something wrong with combining the code and printing directly to the worksheet with the rows from the SQL? What have you tried and how did that not work?

Comment: If you do not care enough about your question to answer comments, it is unlikely that other people will.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is with the hashref and dereferencing it properly.  It's a subtle mistake easily made when just starting out.

```
my $hashref;
while ( $hashref = $curHnd->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
        printf("Row1: >%s<\n",      $hashref->{Row1}),
        printf("Row2: >%s<\n",      $hashref->{Row2}),
        printf("Row3:      >%s<\n", $hashref->{Row3})
}
```

A hashref is a reference to a [hash](https://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes) and they are sweet, *especially* when you use [postfix dereferencing](https://www.perl.com/article/68/2014/2/13/Cool-new-Perl-feature--postfix-dereferencing/) like I've done in the example.
The `$hash{row1}` code you were using is for accessing the value for row1 in `%hash`.  (and for completeness, the *old* way of dereferencing a hashref would be `${$hashref}{row1}` )

You don't really need `@row` array there.  You were only ever assigning to the first element `$row[0]`, so why not just use a scalar.

As for writing out to Excel, I think you'll be using the [write method](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#WORKSHEET-METHODS) inside the while loop and incrementing the row counter with `$row++` .

If you're going to be doing a lot of DBI coding, pick up a copy of *Programming the Perl DBI* by Descartes and Bunce for chapters 4 and 5.  Old but still incredibly useful. (still got mine)